# How could grunt compile all of my scss files to css?

Tags: gruntjs

I've started to learn this just now. I installed the grunt.
If I get `grunt watch` it is automatic but only in case one file.
How could I make it wath all scss file in my theme, and make the css in different folders.
I don't really undestand how could it working in big.

This is my gruntfile.js now:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
 // Project configuration.
 grunt.initConfig({
   pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    connect: {
     uses_defaults: {}
   },
    sass: {
     dev: {
       options: { sourceMap: true },
       files: { 'sites/all/themes/uj/css/uj.styles.css' : 'sites/all/themes/uj/sass/uj.styles.scss' }     
    }
   },
   watch: {
    css: {
      files: 'sites/all/themes/uj/**/*.scss',
      tasks: [ 'sass:dev' ],
      options: { livereload: true }
 }
}



 });
 // Load Grunt plugins
// grunt.loadNpmTasks('');
 // Default task(s).
 grunt.registerTask('default', []);



// Load Grunt plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [official documentation on file globbing](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), to watch for changes for files of a certain file type in the directory path and its subdirectories, you'll want:

```
files: ['js/**/*.js']
```

or:

```
files: ['css/**/*.*']
```

Comment: But if I have scss files in different folders and it should make css-s into a different folders. How will know it where should it put the css?

For example I set this: files: { 'sites/all/themes/uj/css/uj.styles.css' : 'sites/all/themes/uj/sass/uj.styles.scss' } 
So, it knows where is the scss, and where it should put the css.

And the others?

The css-s aren't in the same folder.